# How can I find all possible combinations of vectors that multiply to a fixed product?

Tags: r, combinations

Suppose I have 3 vectors, `L`, `Y`, and `R`. How can I find all possible combinations of `L`, `Y`, and `R` that multiply to a given product?

For example, how can I find all the combinations of `L`, `Y`, and `R` such that `L * Y * R = 6`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brute-force base R solution using `expand.grid` + `subset` + `Reduce`

```
N <- 6
v <- seq(N)[N%%seq(N)==0]
res <- subset(
  res <- expand.grid(rep(list(v),3)),
  Reduce("*",res)==N
)
```

which gives

```
> res
   Var1 Var2 Var3
4     6    1    1
7     3    2    1
10    2    3    1
13    1    6    1
19    3    1    2
25    1    3    2
34    2    1    3
37    1    2    3
49    1    1    6
```

Comment: @keerthana I improved the solution a bit, so it would be faster when `N` is large

Answer (score 0):

What are possible values for your parameters? If not too many, brute-force is always an option:

```r
L_space = seq(-10,10,0.1)
Y_space = seq(-10,10,0.1)
R_space = seq(-10,10,0.1)

for(L in L_space) for(Y in Y_space) for(R in R_space)
  if(L*Y*R==6) print(paste(L,Y,R))
```

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please accept an answer.